# Magento Component Manager: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: magento2

In Magento Component Manager, I am trying to *Sign in to sync your Magento Marketplace purchases*:

[image: Sign in to sync your Magento Marketplace purchases]

I get the following error:

**SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

[image: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]

What's wrong?

Comment: Not sure. You are using your magento.com authentication key? As an alternative, try the [**System Configuration**](http://bit.ly/1OPhIAA) option

Comment: Same here: when I click save, it says `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` http://i.imgur.com/rtjKu4n.png

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. If you haven't already, open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues). This looks like a bug.

Comment: aaaaaaand here I am again. sometimes, SE is like time travel and meeting your past self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Another user posted a link to solve the problem, but then deleted his answer somehow.)

The problem occured on my local machine using XAMPP. It's not a Magento problem, it's a **cURL** problem: cURL does not trust my own, self-signed SSL certificate.

Here's how to fix it: https://serverfault.com/questions/633644/adding-a-self-signed-cert-to-the-trusted-certs-within-curl-in-windows

If it still does not work, make sure the cacert.pem file is mentioned in php.ini: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-solve-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-while-facebook-authentication/replies/104758

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Just had to wait a few days until SO allowed me to do so :)

Comment: First fix works like a charm! 
I use xampp php 7.0.15 and magento 2.1.5

Comment: @ManuelM  For wamp, ant idea?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the wisest idea, but for a local environment can work even without generating self signed certificates:

In `<magento2_root>/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/MarketplaceManager.php`

change this:
`protected $urlPrefix = 'https://';`
into
`protected $urlPrefix = 'http://';`

This is really a modification of a core file, so avoid this method if you can solve the problem with a certificate.

**Update**: In 2.1.x the file to edit is `<magento2_root>/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PackagesAuth.php`